# Jquery AJAX Alert on change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How to alert if another data added to the database? 
in this case everysecond there is an alert how can i apply this to have a notification when another data is fetched.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get('functions/today_sched.php', function (data) {
            $('#today').html(data);
            alert('change')
        });
    }, 1000); 
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id = "today"></div>
```

**today_sched.php**

```
<?php 
                $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","schedule");
                $date = date("d/m/Y");

                $count=1;
                $sel_query="Select * from today_schedule where date = '$date'";
                $result = mysqli_query($con,$sel_query);



                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                <tr>
                  <td>echo $row['date'];</td> 
                </tr>
                $count++;
                }
?>
```

Comment: You would need to install a trigger on the database or similar.  This is not something you could do efficiently by polling.

Comment: Not clear what you’re asking here. Are you asking for an alternative to `alert` every second, which has got to be the most annoying user experience possible? By the way, you have a very expensive script here. Every second you are running `$('#today')`, which runs over a hundred lines of jQuery just to find what you found a second ago. You should create a variable, and use that instead.

Comment: is it more understandable now?

Comment: Not that clear though, but wouldn't you just use jQuery  ´ success ´ to update the div and avoid this annoying alert ?

Comment: yes i just put it there and means that i want alert on a new data fetched

Comment: ok then how can i apply $.ajax here?

Comment: If I get this right (not still sure though), **if** PHP response shows a `schedule` that has been altered/added/modified, then you want to go through jQuery and attach it to a div -> `$("#today").html("New data added !");`is that the point ?